# Using Android Plugin: Nonexistent function 'getPluginName' in base 'JNISingleton'

Tags: android, plugins, godot

**Godot version:** 3.2.3

**Issue description:**
I am new at using Android Plugins in Godot, so I created this simple plugin with only one method.

```
public class GodotProva extends GodotPlugin
{
    public GodotProva(Godot godot) {
        super(godot);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getPluginName() {
        return "mylibrary";
    }
}
```

I tried to use it in Godot, with the following code:

```
func _pressed():
    if Engine.has_singleton("mylibrary"):
        var singleton = Engine.get_singleton("mylibrary")
                print(singleton.getPluginName())
```

I created an apk and installed it on my Android device. The problem is that when I press the button (and the function _pressed() is called), I can see from the logcat the error `Nonexistent function 'getPluginName' in base 'JNISingleton'`

I am sure that the plugin is found, because the "singleton" variable is not null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Android Studio tells me getPluginMethods is deprecated. What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in Godot I can only call custom functions. The methods of the class GodotPlugin (such as getPluginName, getPluginMethods...) cannot be directly called.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to define methods in `getPluginMethods` in my `GodotPlugin` like this:

```java
    public void firstMethod() {
        // TODO
    }

    public void secondMethod() {
        // TODO
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<String> getPluginMethods() {
        return Arrays.asList("firstMethod", "secondMethod");
    }
```

I don't know why this case is not documented, but I wasted a lot of time on this and I think it would be useful for other people...